# Images to stop toggling when mouseover but resume on mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, mouseover, mouseout

I have images that toggle between each other and when you hover over them they stop, but when you move away the mouse it doesn't want to resume the toggle. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
   var t;

  addEventListener("load", () => {
    var index = 0;
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slides");
    const classHide = "slides-hidden",
      count = slides.length;
    nextSlide();
    function nextSlide() {
      slides[index++ % count].classList.add(classHide);
      slides[index % count].classList.remove(classHide);
      t = setTimeout(nextSlide, 500);
    }
  });

   $(".portfolio-image").mouseover(function () {
    if (t) {
      t = clearTimeout(t);
  }
  });

  $(".portfolio-image").mouseout(function () {
    if (t) {
      t = setTimeout(nextSlide, 500);
  }
  });
```

Comment: What does this do?: `const classHide = "slides-hidden", count = slides.length;`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help you:

```
$(".portfolio-image").mouseover(function () {
    if (t) {
      clearTimeout(t);
  }
  });
```

Comment: the clearTimeout(); works but it doesn't want to reset the setTimeout(); on mouseout()

Comment: so change it from setTimeout() and clearTimeout() to setInterval() and clearInterval()

Comment: it jumps into a feedback so I've put the line outside my function but the efect is the same. It doesn't want to resume the intervals

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "setTimeout" get called once, you want use "setInterval" and "clearInterval" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it with some help from you guys. setInterval is better for this task and I had to put it in the same scope as the variable *t* because it wasn't being read.

```
  var t;

  addEventListener("load", () => {

    var index = 0;
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slides");
    const classHide = "slides-hidden",
      count = slides.length;
    nextSlide();
    t = setInterval(nextSlide, 500);
    function nextSlide() {
      slides[index++ % count].classList.add(classHide);
      slides[index % count].classList.remove(classHide);
    }

   $(".portfolio-image").mouseover(function () {
      clearInterval(t);
  });

  $(".portfolio-image").mouseout(function () {
    t = setInterval(nextSlide, 100);
  });

  });
```

Thanks!